# Question about 'Service Fabric cluster' page in Azure Portal

Tags: azure-service-fabric

From  'Service Fabric cluster' page in Azure Portal, I see there is a section showing how many nodes I have in the 'Service Fabric cluster' and then underneath it, it shows home many application I have in that 'Service Fabric cluster'.

My question is how can I find out which applications are running in which nodes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To visualize apps & services on individual nodes, you can use the [Service Fabric explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-visualizing-your-cluster). Navigate to `https://clusterFQDN:19080` (replace clusterFQDN with the full URL of your Azure cluster)

- Open the 'Cluster' treenode,
- Next open 'Nodes'. This will show you all cluster nodes,
- Expand one of the nodes. You can see which apps & services are running on it.